# How to make super method compulsory to run?

Tags: java

Assuming that there are 2 classes `Base` and `Extended`

```
public class Base{
    public void runThis(){
        //... code
    }
}

public class Extended extends Base{
    public void runThis(){
        //... code
    }
}
```

How to make the compiler say that there's a compilation error because Extended.runThis() does not contain the statement `super.runThis();`?

Comment: This literally is a situation in which I run into sometimes. However, the workaround I found is to add some components as the the children that execute in a specified order before/after the execution of the important method takes place. I don't think that would be an acceptable answer for you, so I am writing this in the comment box instead.